# Как правильно перезагрузить оператор сравнения двух матриц==?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Здраствуйте. Как правильно перезагрузить оператор сравнения двух матриц. Выводит такую ​​ошибку: "expression must have bool type ".

```
Matrix operator==(Matrix matr1) {
            Matrix tmp(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                         if (matr[i][k] == matr1[k][j])
            return tmp;
        }
       --------
       if (A == B) {};
```

Comment: так в ошибке и написано что не так. Оператор сравнения должен возвращать булево значение, а ты возвращаешь вместо типа bool тип Matrix

Comment: Гм, а что вы хотите, чтоб он делал? Он у вас возвращает **матрицу** - это так и нужно? Тогда что должно проверять выражение `if (M)`, где `M` - матрица? И, кстати, ну зачем вам передавать в оператор сравнения копию сравниваемой матрицы? передавайте константную ссылку, это самое правильное. Да и оператор делайте константным..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Но для этого варианта оператор [] тоже должен быть перегружен.

```
class Matrix{
    private:
    int n; // кол-во строк
    int m; // кол-во столбцов
    // ваш код
    public:
    // ваш код
    friend bool operator == (Matrix &F, Matrix &S);
}

bool operator == (Matrix &F, Matrix &S){
    if(F.n != S.n || F.m != S.m) return false;
    for(int i = 0;i < F.n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < F.m;j++){
            if(F[i][j] != S[i][j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

В итоге если у вас хоть один i,j элемент не совпадает возвращаете false.